# From files with same name but different extension(*.pdf and *.rtf), if *.rtf is newer, output message on console

Tags: powershell

I have folders and subfolders with files with two different extensions. I need to check the lastwrite time of both corresponding files.
For example

```
file1.rtf
file1.pdf
file2.rtf
file2.pdf
file3.rtf
file3.pdf
```

... and so on

I need to make sure that RTF files ran before PDF files. If the PDF is older than RTF, that means it's an error. I need to output those file names on powershell console with a message indicating this error. Any help would be appreciated. I tried to find and run different codes I found online, but nothing worked. Thank you. the code the code

```
$path = Read-Host "Enter Path"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "*.txt"            

$files | %{ 
    $rtf=$($_.BaseName+".rtf")
    If (Test-Path $rtf){
    If ($_.LastWritetime -lt (Get-Item $rtf).LastWriteTime){

    $file = $_.OpenText();            
    $lineNum = 1;            
    Write-Host "Checking file"$_.Name -f Yellow  "$_ is older than $rtf file"   ;            
    while($file.EndOfStream -ne $true)            
    {   
        $line = $file.ReadLine();                    
        if($line -ne $null)            
        {  
            if($line.ToLower().Contains("error") -or $line.ToLower().Contains("exception"))            
            {  
                Write-Host "Line: $lineNum " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green;            
                Write-Host $line -f Red;            
            }            
        }             

        $lineNum++;                   
    }            
}            
}
}
```

Comment: The result I am expecting is, compare both RTF and Txt file first. then start parsing txt file for key word "error" if it exists, write the txt file name and line with error from the txt file on console. in case the txt file ran before RTF file, also write the message txt is older than $rtf file.

Comment: I think the problem is not CD'ing to the path. The $rtf is build only from the base name without path, so Test-Path will fail because the requested file is not in the current path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set-Location C:\Path\To\Files\
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.rtf |ForEach-Object {
    $pdf=$($_.BaseName+".pdf")
    If (Test-Path $pdf){
        If ($_.LastWritetime -gt (Get-Item $pdf).LastWriteTime){
            Write-Warning "$_ is newer than $pdf file"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Further help needed! Although LotPings code is working really well. I need to add this code to another code I am running for Parsing Files.

Comment: Adding Lotpings code to another code to parse txt file (instead of PDF i mentioned earlier)  ultimately after comparing the time stamp with RTF

Comment: Sanjay, this is in fact a new question. To get attention you should put it as such. This question already has an accepted answer. Follow up readers have to jump between Q & A & comments to understand whats going on.

Comment: I totally understand and I truly appreciate your suggestion. I will keep this in mind and going to raise a new question. Thank you LotPings and sorry for any inconvenience. I am a new learner new to this system. I will raise new question today.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to group the files by their base names (the file name without the extension) and then see which one in each group is oldest:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Path\To\Files\* -Include *.pdf,*.rtf |Group-Object BaseName |ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Count -lt 2){
        Write-Warning "Only $($_.Group[0].Name) is present"
    }
    else{
        $Oldest = $_.Group |Sort-Object LastWriteTime |Select-Object -First 1
        if($Oldest.Extension -eq '.pdf'){
            Write-Warning "$($Oldest.Name) is older than RTF file"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias! I truly appreciate your quick response. it was awesome. Although it did not give me complete results but the addition made by mklement0 worked completely fine. I so, truly appreciate both of your help. I will be in touch if needed as I am incorporating this code inside another code. Thank you once again both of you.

Comment: The code is running fine! the issue is though, when one of the file is missing or not available, it gives wrong results. for example if the .rtf is missing, the code is automatically consider pdf as if it is older and if PDF is missing, i get no warnings at all and those single files are being skipped. is there any way it also checks if both files are available or not first. if one is missing, we can output warning indicating which file is missing and of course if both available, do the same what we are already doing. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Sanjay Updated the snippet to test whether less than 2 files are contained in each group